# Putting a button in table footer view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I am creating a custom button and putting it in my table's footer view but the button is going way out from the right corner.

What is wrong here!?!

Here is my code and output image:

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.56] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:kButtonSliceWidth topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitle:@"Click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize14]];
    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 300.0, 44.0)];
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:aButton];
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the frame be : (0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)?

Comment: @Vince: That'd result in the button drawn on the top left corner, which I'm sure Abhinav doesn't want.

Comment: Why don't you try settin the frame like this `CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, self.tableView.frame.size.width - 20, 44.0)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I added the button in the UIView and then set the tableFooterView to this UIView object and it worked. We cannot directly put UIButton as tableFooterView.

Comment: You can, but table view sets the autoResizingMask to all four corners. You should change it to get it working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this.    Set `IBOutlet UIView *footerView;` and synthesize it. Add it as a subview using the method-

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(footerView == nil) {
    //allocate the view if it doesn't exist yet
    footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];


    //create the button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 300, 44)];

    //set title, font size and font color
    [button setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];

    //set action of the button
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add the button to the view
    [footerView addSubview:button];
}

//return the view for the footer
return footerView;
}
```

Comment: From UITableView.h: `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView;                            // accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
`

Answer (score -3):

One important addition to Legolas' fine answer: You'll need to implement the tableView delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    foot 50;
}
```

This was driving me nuts because the button (or, in my case, buttons) were not responding to the touch event.  Adding the delegate method made it all better. :-)

Comment: Legolas answer isn't fine in this case because tableFooterView != footerInSection, and Abhinav asked for first one. The first is for whole table, the second only for section (and you can have a lot of them). Check EmilioPelaez comment.